# Typescript: pick from type not interface?

Tags: typescript

I have a type:

```
export type MyType = 'something' | 'another' | 'else';
```

Then I would like to use just some of its options:

```
Interface MyInterface {
   selection: Pick<MyType, 'something' | 'another'>
}
```

But getting the error `type doesn't satisfy the constraint`

Is it not possible to use Pick on types but only on interfaces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) is about properties. You need to use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
type MyType = 'something' | 'another' | 'else';

interface MyInterface {
   selection: Extract<MyType, 'something' | 'another'>;
}
```